# How can I find an ID by Value in a List?

Tags: java, swt

down to the basics.

JAVA 1.7 SWT.

I've one text field and onle List.
While the user is enter something into the text field,  the frist matching value in the list should be select.

I try it out with `list.selection(list.indexOf(value))` but  `list.indexOf(value)` returns only the  ID of the string which is entered completely.

I'm pretty sure, that it is not a good practice to check all the characters from each value in the list.

Does anyone can give me a hint what the best practice will be?

Michael

Comment: how is your list defined? there is an error somewhere?

Comment: `List list = new List(composite_1, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);` There are just strings in there. I added the values by `this.list.add(value)`

Comment: if you are trying to do an incremental or partial search you should go through all the elements of the list, compare if the text from each item is starting with your text  and select the item in the list. there is no selection function in the List for partial match

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. If you want to do auto-completion of text in a `Text` control look at the `AutoCompleteField` JFace class.

Comment: Well, I try an other explanation: I 've a list with the names "ANTON, ANDREA, MICHAEL, MARIA, MARC, KERSTIN".
If i write the first letter "M" into the text field, "MICHAEL" should be selected. Then I insert an "A" into the text field. Now there is "MA", so "MARIA" should be selected - "MICHAEL" stays in the list, but is never selected. And if I add "RI" to the text textfield ( now "MARI" ),"MARIA" is selected in the text field.

Comment: Are the list items always ordered alphabetically?

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have a Text widget here is a piece of code to acomplish what you need:

```
    final Text textbox = new Text(composite_1, SWT.BORDER);
    textbox.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
      @Override
      public void modifyText(ModifyEvent arg0) {
        String s = textbox.getText();
        if (s.length() == 0) {
          list.deselectAll();
          return;
        }
        String[] items = list.getItems();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          if (items[i].startsWith(s)) {
            // found the first item which match the typed text (case sensitive) in the textbox, select it and stop
            list.select(i);
            break;
          }
        }
      }  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've  done..

```
String pattern ="^"+item+"\\w*\\_*"; 

for(int j = 0 ; j < lstTables.getItemCount(); j++){ 
    if(list.getItem(j).matches(pattern) == true){ 
        list.select(j); 
        list.showSelection(); 
        lstTables.setBackground(Colorlist.textfieldClear); 
        lstTables.setFocus(); 
        return true; 
        } 
    }
```